# Hardware anisotropic mipmaps - can you get each dimension scaled independently

Tags: opengl, direct3d, mipmaps

The **anisotropic** mipmap theory from Wikipedia etc seems to indicate that for a N-dimensional texture you want a N-dimensional set of (N-dimensional) mipmaps.

Eg: a 2D 4x4 mipmap should have nine 2D mipmap images total in a 2-dimensional array (of size 3x3) of 2D images (ie, effectively a kind-of 4D array of pixels):

```
[4x4, 2x4, 1x4],
[4x2, 2x2, 1x2],
[4x1, 2x1, 1x1]
```

instead of just the three 2D mipmaps in a 1-dimensional array (of size 3):

```
4x4, 2x2, 1x1
```

See the satellite picture on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_filtering.

So, in general, a 2D texture with dimensions `X=2^A` and `Y=2^B` (where ^ means raised to power) should have `A * B` ***anisotropic*** mipmaps, holding a total of `4 * (X - 1) * (Y - 1)` pixels.

Yet the OpenGL and D3D(11) documentation and interfaces all seem to just use the 1-D mipmap set (4x4, 2x2, 1x1).

---

My questions are:

1) Is there a proper term for this *flavor* of mipmapping that I should be using (to help me google)?

2) Does modern 3D hardware support this?

3) If so, how do you achieve this on D3D or OpenGL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears I didn't actually read all the Wikipedia page as the answer is right there - Rip Mapping.